# rails 3.2 nested form doesn't call update when I send it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I'm using a form with another nested form inside of it and I would like to update nested elements, but it doesn't work...

env : Rails 3.2

**_form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for [:pim, activity]
  ...
  = f.simple_fields_for :pictures do |pic_form|                                                       
    %div.media
      .pull-left.col-md-2
        = image_tag pic_form.object.image.mini.url
      %div.media-body.col-md-5
        = pic_form.input :alt
      = pic_form.input :element_id, as: :hidden
      = pic_form.input :element_type, as: :hidden
      = pic_form.input :_destroy, as: :hidden
```

Activity has X pictures:

**activity.rb**

```
has_many :pictures, :as => :element, :dependent => :destroy
...
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true
```

When I modify the input of nested element, the server trace is:

```
 Picture Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."element_id" = 13579 AND "pictures"."element_type" = 'Activity' AND "pictures"."id" IN (9839, 9840, 9838)
```

But 0 update... and 0 errors...

Do you have any idea what's going on? I have tried many solutions, but they don't work.
Thanks.

**EDIT**: I forgot, but in Activity's form_for it edits two nested forms and the second form works very well.......

**EDIT**

```
 ********************************************************************************
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"cbOJlat6uT3vIKrb2xaNXaD1osWTHL3435gALI8NDBU=",
 "activity"=>{"id"=>"13579",
          "name"=>"dw",
          "category_id"=>"27",
          "address"=>"",
          "description"=>"",
          "description_source"=>"",
          "details"=>"",
          "from_price"=>"46",
          "pictures_attributes"=> {"0"=>{"source"=>"sq",
                                         "element_id"=>"13579",                           
                                         "element_type"=>"Activity",
                                         "_destroy"=>"false",
                                         "id"=>"9840"},
                                   "1"=>{"source"=>"str de base",
                                         "element_id"=>"13579",
                                         "element_type"=>"Activity",
                                         "_destroy"=>"false",
                                         "id"=>"9839"},
                                   "2"=>{"source"=>"",
                                         "element_id"=>"13579",
                                         "element_type"=>"Activity",
                                         "_destroy"=>"false",
                                         "id"=>"9838"}},
          "csv_id"=>"italy",
          "options_attributes"=> {"0"=>{"name"=>"a",
                                        "description"=>"",
                                        "code_pre"=>"",
                                        "code_type"=>"",
                                        "activity_id"=>"13579",
                                        "_destroy"=>"false",
                                        "id"=>"38"}}
          },
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "action"=>"update",
 "controller"=>"pim/activities",
 "locale"=>"fr",
 "id"=>"13579"}
 (print generate by `pr params`)
 ********************************************************************************

 Activity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "13579"]]
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 Picture Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."element_id" = 13579 AND "pictures"."element_type" = 'Activity' AND "pictures"."id" IN (9840, 9839, 9838)
 Option Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "options".* FROM "options" WHERE "options"."activity_id" = 13579 AND "options"."id" IN (38)
 (0.3ms)  UPDATE "activities" SET "ids" = '"csv_id"=>"italy-5" "updated_at" = '2014-04-28 15:23:16.962313' WHERE "activities"."id" = 13579
 (0.1ms)  UPDATE "options" SET "ids" = '"code_pre"=>"","code_type"=>""', "updated_at" = '2014-04-28 15:23:16.963988' WHERE "options"."id" = 38
 (3.7ms)  COMMIT
 Redirected to http://localhost:3000/fr/pim/activities/13579/edit
```

source "sq" it's a new string

```
 "pictures_attributes"=> {"0"=>{"source"=>"sq",
```

source "str de base" it is the value in bdd

```
 "1"=>{"source"=>"str de base",
```

**activities_controller.rb**

```
def update
       pr params, decorator: '*'                                                                             
       @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
       params[:activity].delete(:id)
       if @activity.update_attributes(params[:activity])
         redirect_to edit_pim_activity_path(@activity), flash: { success: I18n.t("pim.activities.saved") }
       else
         render :new, error: I18n.t("pim.activities.error")
       end   
     end
```

**picture.rb**

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  IMAGE_SIZES = {
    mini: [100, 100]
  }
  mount_uploader :image, PictureUploader

  belongs_to :element, :polymorphic => true

  belongs_to :point, foreign_key: :element_id, foreign_type: 'Point'

  after_save :element_changed

  def element_changed
    if !self.element_type.nil? && self.element_type_changed?
      self.image.recreate_versions!
    end
  end

  def to_jq_read
    {
      "tall" => image.tall.url,
    }
  end

  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "id" => id,
      "name" => read_attribute(:image),
      "size" => image.size,
      "url" => image.url,
      "tiny" => image.tiny.url,
     "small" => image.small.url,
     "tall" => image.tall.url,
      "delete_url" => admin_picture_path(:id => id),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE"
    }
  end

  def featured_big_url
    self.image.featured_big.url
  end

  def featured_small_url
    self.image.featured_small.url
  end
  def self.remove_by_params(pictures)
    pictures.each do |pic|
      picture = Picture.find(pic.second[:id])
      picture.destroy
    end
  end

  def self.destroy_by_ids(ids)
    ids.each do |id|
      if picture = Picture.find(id)
        picture.destroy
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `update` action in the question. Also, add the complete server log that you get upon form submission including the `params` hash.

Comment: I edit my first post, when I update on "option" all works (for option update), with "picture" nothing...

Comment: Also share the code for `update` action  from your controller in the question.

Comment: I put the update action from activities controller

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Can you share the `Picture` model in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I add picture.rb model.

Answer (score 0):

Did you allowed the mass assignment for pictures_attributes doing:

```
attr_accessible :pictures_attributes
```

For more info: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible

Comment: if I try our response I have an rails error : "Can't mass-assign protected attributes"  
    

Also I try yesterday to put all my attr in Pictures to accessible but I havn't change.